# Calculate pipe size and friction loss for an agricultural project?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, friction, velocity, water, flow

I'm in the process of designing a water system for our regenerative agricultural project in the Horn of Africa.

I'm looking to install a ≈1000L water tank on a 3 meter stand which will gravity supply a secondary ≈1000L water tank ≈320 meters downhill with a ≈5.8m elevation drop. Piping connecting the two tanks will be PVC, probably 1"-1.25" as anything larger would be uneconomical.

I am trying to determine if this setup will work by gravity without an inline pump between the two tanks, and if the lower tank can also be on a 2-3m stand or if it needs to be lower. If necessary, an inline pump can be added but will be difficult as the project is off-grid.

Using multiple [Omni](https://www.omnicalculator.com/) calculators ([velocity](https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/pipe-flow), [flow rate](https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/flow-rate), [friction loss](https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/friction-loss)) , I've determined, if using a 1" pipe:

- The flow velocity would be **0.603 m/s**
- The flow rate would be **18.33 L/min**
- The friction head loss would be **5.787 meters** of water.

I'm not sure where to go from here with these calculations, what this determines, or if I'm even on the right path! I haven't done any calculations with water head yet, which I'm assuming would be 3 meters (the height of the upper water tank stand) as the upper tank will not always be full, so better to design as if the water level is low (?).

I appreciate any insights!

Thanks in advance,

Jonathan

**EDIT:** Revisiting this, I initially wrote the drop at 5.8m, but thinking I should add the 3m from the height of the tank stand? To a total drop of 8.8m. Either way, it appears the friction loss leaves me with less than 15cm of static head at the lower tank (when subtracting the friction head loss from the head/drop).

If I incorporate a ball valve at the upper tank to regulate/lower the flow rate, that seems to fix the problem? If I halve the flow rate in the friction loss calculator, the friction head loss drops drastically. Is this a proper workaround?

With a drop of 8.8m from the top of the upper tank stand, using a 1" plastic pipe, the friction head loss is 8.785m... basically unusable when after subtracting this from the head/drop, right? But halving the flow rate from 22.77(L/min) (the new flow rate with a drop of 8.8 instead of 5.8), the friction head loss is only 2.28m, leaving 6.52m of static head (8.8m - 2.28m).

Can anyone confirm my math is right? Or am I totally doing these calculations wrong? Thanks

Comment: The difference in level is 5.8m for a distance of 320m, the system will work and to regulate the flow, simply add a valve between the two tanks.

Comment: When I was in Morocco, we had a tank of +- 2500 l (water from a well) at a distance of +- 100m and a difference in level of +-4m, the system worked even if we stop the electric pump *, we need a valve at the end of the pipe (flexible of 1" I think) so that it remains always filled with water.
*https://www.otelo.be/catalogue/pompe-eau-surpresseur-automatique/hyline-0017280510-skg.html

Comment: $1000 l/18.33 (l/min) = 54.6 min$

Comment: See new edit. Is my math right?